# how to view the installed provisioning certificate on device in itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

how to check the installed certificates on device and see if there is any certificate installed or not.Beause i am having problem  while installing app on device

Comment: Take a look into `Settings->General->Profile` on your device.

Comment: @Adam: that is, in fact, the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iPhone Configuration Utility instead, it's a lot quicker than iTunes, plus you can view all installed profiles on a device.
Mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465
Win: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466

Or just do what Adam said: Settings->General-Profile.